# How to use a Jython module from within Java?

Tags: java, jython

I've created a "python module/library" and Jython seemed to be able to compile the files to .class files.

Is it possible to use this module as a Library in usual Java Code? / Is it possible to Access those functions and methods from the module from within Java?

Comment: If it's .class files, it should be.  We'd need some details to help you further.  Did you compile it into a .jar file?

Comment: The Jython Interpreter doesn't give you the option to compile it straight to a jar file.

Comment: The JDK comes with a command line Jar tool that you can use to make a .jar file: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

Comment: Also, depending on your environment, you may be able to use the classpath to access individual .class files: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: I can indeed use these class files when I access them using the Jython Interpreter but not through the "default" java one. I just wanted to ask whether its still possible to accomplish something like that.

Comment: Basically you should be able to, but I have no idea how to go about it without some details about what it is you are actually doing.